# How to properly define custom event time-stamp fields in ETW, to be used as StartTime and EndTime for gannt graph in WPA?

Tags: etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I'm interested in getting custom ETW events to display *Start Time* and *End Time*, like some default windows events do, in order to present it in gantt form, like so:

[image: Desired result for custom ETW Events]

I've hacked around [Bruce Dawson's demo](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/xperf-basics-recording-a-trace-the-easy-way/) manifest and multi-provider files, to add *Start Time* and *End Time* fields to one of the event templates.

However, I can't get it to even recognize the field as a Time field.

I compose the template for the event payload as described in [Microsoft's specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382774(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows

```
<data inType="win:FILETIME" outType="xs:dateTime" name="Start Time" />           
<data inType="win:FILETIME" outType="xs:dateTime" name="End Time" />
```

And convert my QueryPerformanceCounter variables accordingly :

```
//start is LARGE_INTEGER
//end is LARGE_INTEGER

FILETIME ftStart;
ftStart.dwLowDateTime = start.LowPart;
ftStart.dwHighDateTime = start.HighPart;

FILETIME ftEnd;
ftEnd.dwLowDateTime = end.LowPart;
ftEnd.dwHighDateTime = end.HighPart;
```

WPA says "Unable to parse data" in the relevant fields:
[image: WPA unable to parse data]

Then I look at [Microsoft WPA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448109.aspx):

> If the graph is a Gantt chart, each column that you move to the graphing elements area must contain only timestamp values. 
>   A mark in one of the horizontal bars in the Gantt chart represents one timestamp value.

So I look and see that timestamps are simply LARGE_INTs so I go back to original format and write the manifest like so:

```
<data inType="win:UInt64" outType="win:ETWTIME" name="Start Time" />           
<data inType="win:UInt64" outType="win:ETWTIME" name="End Time" />
```

Then the data is presented as a large count of nanoseconds instead of time.
And I'm unable to select either field as "Start Time" or "End Time".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you have figured this out?

Comment: Nope, but I use activities instead to mark start and end